# Printing (hidden) iframe prints a blank page on IE

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer, iframe

So, first I tried several solutions proposed in similar questions I found on SO, but so far I didn't find a way to make it work.

In the end of my view, I have :

```
<iframe ng-if="clientPDFUrl" id="clientPDF" 
        ng-src="{{originURL + clientPDFUrl}}" ng-hide="true">
</iframe>
<iframe ng-if="CACPDFUrl" id="CACPDF" 
        ng-src="{{originURL + CACPDFUrl}}" ng-hide="true">
</iframe>
```

Then I have a modal like that :

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">Printing</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <button ng-click="localPrintPDF('CACPDF')" 
          class="btn btn-normal generate-pdf-button">Print for CAC
  </button>
  <button ng-click="localPrintPDF('clientPDF')"
          class="btn btn-normal generate-pdf-button">Print for client
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-normal">Annuler</button>
</div>
```

And finally the controller :

```
angular.module('app.edition').controller('printingModalController', [
  '$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$modalInstance', 'APIClientService',
  function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $modalInstance, APIClientService) {
    $scope.localPrintPDF = function(frameId) {
      var frameContent = document.getElementById(frameId).contentWindow;

      frameContent.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $modalInstance.dismiss(false);
    };
  }
]);
```

So, this works fine in Chrome, but prints a blank page using IE.

**Things I tried so far :**

- Replacing`ng-hide="true"` with `style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"`
- Using `frameContent.print()` instead of `frameContent.document.execCommand('print', false, null);`
- Using `focus()` before using `print()`
- Using `window.frames[frameId].print()` (With a `focus()` first)

So, any suggestion to make the printing work on IE ? I could use something else than an iframe maybe.

Comment: What version of IE is? Are you getting an error in the developer console?

Comment: I'm using IE 11.0.9600.18426. No error show up in the console